# Content is outside of svg tag

Tags: html, svg

I was just testing some basic SVG stuff.
I have a SVG tag with a simple P in it, yet the P is displayed outside of the SVG tag.

So my question is, why does this happen?

Note: I'm using an online editor (playcode.io).

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <p>test</p>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: `<p>` is a HTML element, not a SVG element. It doesn't make sense to use it this way. Learn about the [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element.

Comment: @ccprog You're right. Thank you, I am quite new to SVGs, but that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I just needed a simple text element since you can't use HTML elements in an SVG.  Thanks to ccprog